# How can I avoid the void assignment in this code?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `VariantType` that can be empty, i.e. has a void state.

The following code, when compiling with Mingw Builds x64 5.3.0 generates the error:

```
error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'VariantType {aka utils::Variant<bool, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >}' requested|
```

How can I avoid the error:

```
#include <Common/Variant.hpp>
using namespace utils;

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

using VariantType = Variant<bool,int,std::string>;

class EFBase
{
public:
    virtual ~EFBase() {}
};

template<typename FuncSig>
class EF : public EFBase
{
public:

    EF(std::function<FuncSig> func) : m_function(func) {};

    std::function<FuncSig> m_function;
};

class Functions
{
public:

    using FuncMap = std::map<std::string,EFBase*>;

    FuncMap m_functions;

    template<typename FuncType>
    void Add(const std::string name, FuncType function)
    {
        m_functions.emplace(FuncMap::value_type(name,new EF<FuncType>(std::function<FuncType>(function))));
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    VariantType Invoke(const std::string& name, Args... args)
    {
        auto itr = m_functions.find(name);
        if(itr == m_functions.end())
            return VariantType();

        typedef void Func(typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type...);
        std::type_index index(typeid(Func));

        const EFBase& a = *itr->second;
        std::function<Func> func = static_cast<const EF<Func>&>(a).m_function;
        if(typeid(typename std::function<Func>::result_type) == typeid(void))
        {
            func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            return VariantType();
        }
        else
        {
            VariantType x = func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            return x;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Functions f;
    f.Add<int(bool)>("get3",[](bool x) { return 3; });

    VariantType v = f.Invoke<>("get3",true);

    return 0;
}
```

I would've thought that the check for the `result_type` of the function object would have been enough; but I guess it's not because of the template instantiation. Do I need a sort of helper struct that does something different in a void case (based on template params)?

The purpose of the code is to store functions of arbitrary signature in a map by name so that they can be called upon later. The `VariantType` handles the multiple possible return values.

The error is on the assignment in the `else` block of the `Invoke` method.

The `VariantType` is a fair bit of code, so I didn't provide it (I'm not sure it's pertinent anyway). But I can if needed.

Comment: From what I suppose,  when you try to do the assignment in your else block,  you are invoking the func object which returns a void and it is not compatible with your VariantType neither through an implicit conversion.

Comment: Note that `typename std::function<Func>::result_type` will always evaluate to `void` with that definition of `Func`, and `EF<Func>::m_function` will always have a function signature that returns `void`.  I don't think it will be easy to implement a map of heterogeneous functions like you're trying to do here without some external library.  At the least, each thing in your collection of `m_function`s will need to keep track of its type at runtime to be used in some sort of runtime downcast; it can't be done statically as you're trying here, unless the use case is simpler.

Comment: (incidentally, `std::is_same`, or better `std::is_same_v` is likely a better way to test if types are the same than using `typeid`)

Comment: Thanks @mkal I see the problem with the void return types now.

Comment: @mkal, surely there's some way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact use case, one suggestion would be to store `std::function<VariantType(x)>`s in the map (with `x` being some fixed set of parameters), with the idea that the functions will be adapted to a particular signature using functor wrappers for storage.  The client's functions passed to `Add` would then either (a) need to be wrapped in functors that have the correct signature, or (b) if you know all of the different kinds of functions that will ever be passed to `Add`, you could define `template<typename F, typename ...Args> Add(F f)`, and specialize it based on `std::result_of<F(...Args)>` so that `Add` could make the wrappers. You could also do a mixed approach and require that the clients pass functions that conform to the fixed parameter list and `Add` can wrap those functions to return `VariantType`s based on the passed-in function's return type.

An example is below showing some of the concepts.

Note the SFINAE principle being applied to the `wrapper` template overloads to avoid having the compiler fail in the specialization that we don't want it to evaluate (the one where `f` returns `void`).

Also note that I think a situation where you actually need to dispatch different argument lists at runtime depending on the type of function may be a lot more difficult, hence the approach here tries to normalize the argument lists by capturing them when creating the callback.  If you really think you need the variadic argument list in `Invoke`, then I would suggest maybe looking into using `boost::any` to wrap the functions, or at least for conceptual guidance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct Variant
{
    Variant() { std::cout << "In void Ctor of Variant" << std::endl; }
    template<typename T> Variant(T t) { std::cout << "In data Ctor of Variant" << std::endl; }
};

using VariantType = Variant<bool,int,std::string>;
using FuncSig = std::function<VariantType(int)>;


struct Functions
{
    template<typename F, typename Result = typename std::result_of<F(int)>::type >
    void Add(const std::string name, F f)
    {
        this->m_functions.emplace(name, [=](int i) { return wrapper<F, Result>(f, i); });
    }

    VariantType Invoke(const std::string& name, int i)
    {
        auto itr = m_functions.find(name);
        if(itr == m_functions.end())
            return VariantType();

        return itr->second(i);
    }
private:
    using FuncMap = std::map<std::string,FuncSig>;
    FuncMap m_functions;

    template<typename F, typename ReturnValue, typename ...Args>
    static typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<ReturnValue, void>::value, VariantType>::type wrapper(F f, Args&&... args)
    {
        VariantType x = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return x;
    }

    template<typename F, typename ReturnValue, typename ...Args>
    static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<ReturnValue, void>::value, VariantType>::type wrapper(F f, Args&&... args)
    {
        f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return VariantType();
    }
};

struct Client
{
    Client(Functions& funcs)
    {
        funcs.Add("v_func", [&](int i) { this->v_func(this->d, i); } );
        funcs.Add("b_func", [&](int i) { return this->b_func(i); } );
        funcs.Add("s_func", [&](int i) { return this->s_func(i, this->some_string); } );
        funcs.Add("i_func", [&](int i) { return this->i_func(i); } );
    }

    void v_func(double d, int i) const { std::cout << this->obj_name << ": v_func()" << d << ", " << i << std::endl; }
    bool b_func(int i) const { std::cout << this->obj_name << ": b_func()" << i << std::endl; return i > 5; }
    std::string s_func(int i, std::string const& s) const { std::cout << this->obj_name << ": s_func()" << i << ", " << s << std::endl; return s; }
    int i_func(int i) const { std::cout << this->obj_name << ": i_func()" << i << std::endl; return i + 10; }

    std::string obj_name;
    const std::string some_string = "some_string";
    const double d = 3.14;
};

int main()
{
    VariantType variant;
    Functions functions;
    Client c(functions);
    c.obj_name = "Client1";
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "s_func", "b_func", "v_func", "i_func" };
    int i = 0;
    for (auto s : v) { variant = functions.Invoke(s, i++); }

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
In void Ctor of Variant
Client1: s_func()0, some_string
In data Ctor of Variant
Client1: b_func()1
In data Ctor of Variant
Client1: v_func()3.14, 2
In void Ctor of Variant
Client1: i_func()3
In data Ctor of Variant
```

Comment: Thanks @mkal. I've used this and managed to get it storing `VariantType(Args...)`. It's brilliant. Only downside is returned values need to be one of the types that the `typedef VariantType` can hold, but otherwise suits my needs perfectly.

Comment: @NeomerArcana: Cool; glad to hear it's (mostly) working.  I'm curious what other returned value types need to be considered and why? Could `VariantType`'s Ctor handle some sort of conversion from the other types?

Comment: `Variant` ctor can take any value that is in its template types. An `any` tyoe could be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

(for this post, 'generate code' means performing the type substitutions, selection of specializations, and so forth)

Yes; when you want to generate *different code* based on the properties of template parameters, you need to use specialization.

Hiding code in a never-executed block will prevent execution, but it won't prevent code generation.

It doesn't have to be a helper struct; you could use tags:

```
VariantType InvokeHelper(/* args here */, std::true_type) ;
VariantType InvokeHelper(/* args here */, std::false_type) ;

// ...
return InvokeHelper(/* */, std::is_same</* function result*/, void>);
```

but helper structs are probably the better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, as @mkal pointed out above in a comment, the `std::function`s will always be returning void...